# Extract vector from GeoPDF

Tags: qgis

I have encountered problem with GeoPDF consisting both raster and vector objects. While loading to QGIS both of them are rendered as raster layer (vector objects are being rasterized). I have tried to get rid of all raster using Inkscape, as it was only solution I got so far, but it is impossible to find evry "piece" of image, and also it causes loose of reference, so my map is not in correct place anymore.

Is there a way to extract only vector data from this pdf without losing CRS information?

Comment: Did you try adding this via the "add vector layer" option instead of via drag and drop?

Comment: Yes, and I have error regarding data type, same happens while using pure GDAL command line.

Comment: Can QGIS import a vector-only GeoPDF as a vector?

Comment: While trying to import "mixed" pdf QGIS raises an error, while using drag&drop it converts pdf to raster.